# Convert an array of 32bit Color data into 8bit equivlent

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to coding and very new to C#. I have a

```
 Color[] dataArray (
    Color [A=255, R=0, G=255, B=173],
    Color [A=243, R=143, G=006, B=234],
    ...
 )
```

Taken from a Bitmap. I can convert this into the **32bit ARGB** value of the `Color` structure using `.ToArgb()` but I am looking to convert it into the **8bit** color  equivalent. Where each individual pixel is defined by a 3 digit code. What would be the most appropriate why to achieve this?

Comment: Which [8-bit color format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color) are you targeting?

Comment: Format8bppIndexed ? I think that this is the format I need?

Comment: Your example is a 24 bit color not 8 bit

Comment: Please figure out for sure what format you need and report back. The problem is currently underspecified.

Comment: I need 8bit colour format

Comment: There are different types of 8-bit colour formats, for different colour mappings, for an 8-bit output the bit pattern is something like RRRGGGBB - with only two bits for the colour blue, because 3*3 = 9, rather than 8.  Other formats could be any order of colour values! If this is your desired output format, some simple maths can scale the values from 0-255 to 0-7 or 0-3 for blue.  Although, quality mileage may vary and there's probably some C# library somewhere that does the math for you.

Comment: Note also that Format8bbpIndexed also requires a color palette. Is there an existing color palette you have to match? Can you make up your own color palette? Do you want to do straight quantization or do you want to dither? This is in general a hard problem.

Comment: I can match an existing colour palette or make up my own as long as I can match a colour to a quantitative figure. Sorry! My knowledge of C# and graphics is only 2days old!

Comment: @DanWarren You need to choose what 8bit format you want to use. Is Red,Green or Blue 2 bit ? Probably easier to choose a palette first.